# The number of elements required to represent an integer from the set $\{a^m + b^m | m \in \mathbb{N} \} \cup \{1\}$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, optimization, asymptotics, arithmetic

Given a natural number $n$, we know that the number of the binary digits required to represent $n$ is roughly $\log_2(n)$, which is slower than a linear function in $n$. This means that we require at most $\log_2(n)$ elements from the set $\{2^m | m \in \mathbb{N} \}$ that sums up to $n$.

**Question**: what happens if we instead have a set that consists of a sum of exponential expressions (and $1$)? For example, $\{2^m + 3^m | m \in \mathbb{N} \} \cup \{1\}$? What is the bound for the number of elements required that sum up to $n$?

**My thought so far:** I think that the bound is still slower than a linear function because clearly we can just add up $n$ $1$'s to obtain $n$, but I am not sure how to start computing this bound.

Any idea/reference would be really appreciated.

Comment: Can we write every number in such a way at all ?

Comment: I think so, because $1$ is the set.

Comment: $1$ is not in the set , we have $2,5,13,\cdots$. If we can use $2$ and $5$ multiple times, we can get to every natural number except $1$ and $3$ , but I doubt this is what you want.

Comment: @Peter Thank you, I will change the question

Comment: The entries grow fast. For large numbers, we will in general need therefore many summands and many repetitions.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out, the entries also grow slower than an exponential function ($2^m + 3^m \leq 2\times3^m \leq 3^m\times3^m = 9^m$), I am not sure if this helps with anything.

Comment: Any feedback on my answer?

Answer (score -1):

Let $a$ and $b$ be fixed positive integers, where $2\le a<b$. Every positive integer can be written as a sum of at most
$$
(b-1)[1+\log_b n]
$$
numbers of the form $1$ or $a^m+b^m$. This follows from the two results below.

---

> **Lemma**: For all $n\ge 2$, there exists an integer $m$ such that $n\ge a^m+b^m > n/b$.

*Proof:* Given $n\in \Bbb N^+$, where $n\ge 2$, let $m$ be the largest integer such that $a^m+b^m\le n$. It must further be true that $a^m+b^m>n/b$. If not, then we would have
$$
a^{m+1}+b^{m+1}< b(a^m+b^m) \le b\times (n/b)=n,
$$
contradicting the maximality of $m.$ $\tag*{$\blacksquare$}$

---

> **Theorem:** Let $S$ be a set of positive integers such that $1\in S$, and such that for every $n\ge 2$, there exists $s\in S$ such that $n\ge s> n/b$. Then every positive integer can be written as a sum of at most $$(b-1)[1+\log_b(n)]$$ elements of $S$.

*Proof*: The base cases are when $n\in \{1,\dots,b-1\}$. Clearly, these can all be written as a sum of at most $b-1$ elements of $S$, which suffices since $b-1\le (b-1)[1+\log_b n]$ when $n\le b-1$.

For the inductive step, choose $s\in S$ such that $n \ge s > n/b$. Let $k$ be the unique integer such that
$$
n/(k-1) \ge s>n/k. 
$$
Note that $2\le k \le b$. To write $n$ as a sum of elements of $S$, we will use $k-1$ copies of $s$. Letting $r=n-(k-1)s$ be the remainder, the above implies that
$$
0\le  r < n/k,
$$
so our inductive hypothesis implies $r$ can be written as a sum of at most $(b-1)[1+\log_b(n/k)]$ elements of $S$, meaning $n$ can be written as a sum of
$$
(k-1)+(b-1)[1+\log_b(n/k)]\quad \text{elements of $S$.}
$$
The target number is $(b-1)[1+\log_b n]$ elements of $S$, so we will be done if we can prove
$$
(k-1)+(b-1)[1+\log_b(n/k)] \stackrel{?}\le (b-1)[1+\log_b(n)].
$$
This is equivalent to
$$
(k-1)+(b-1)\left[1+\frac{\ln n-\ln k}{\ln b}\right] \stackrel{?}\le (b-1)\left[1+\frac{\ln n}{\ln b}\right],
$$
which simplifies to
$$
\frac{k-1}{\ln k}  \stackrel{?}\le \frac{b-1}{\ln b}.
$$
This last inequality is true since $f(x)=\frac{x-1}{\ln x}$ is an increasing function of $x$ on the interval $[2,\infty)$, and since $2\le k \le b$. $\tag*{$\blacksquare$}$

Comment: Huh, I was pretty happy with this answer, but the downvote suggests there is something wrong with it. I have double-checked my reasoning and found no mistakes. I would appreciate constructive criticism.

Comment: Thank you for your time and detailed answer, I am not sure why there is a downvote, either.